# A general formula to find the solution to $ax^{4}+bx = 0$

Tags: polynomials

I was wondering if there's a general formula or way to find the solution to $ax^{4}+bx = 0$?

Thank you for your help!

Edit: thank you for your answers!
What about the general case $ax^{4}+bx \neq 0$?

Comment: Yes there is. It depends on factorization of polynomials and cubic roots, the latter may or may not exist in the field $a,b$ come from. How much progress did you make yourself?

Comment: Are we solving this over the integers, or over some field? What do you mean by solving $ax^4+bx\neq 0$? Why can't you take $x=1$ for $a+b\neq 0$?

Comment: I'm talking about some constant . $\neq 0$ was not the best choice, sorry!

Answer (score 2):

Yes; there is; because it is equivalent to $x=0$ or $ax^3+b=0$, whose
solutions are easily found.

Comment: You are assuming that the domain has no zero divisors.

Comment: I am pretty sure the OP assumes this as well, but I will stand corrected.

Comment: I guess so, but actually he/she says nothing about it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with real numbers then solutions to the general quartic equation are known but they are not as simple or well known as the famous solution to quadratic equations.

[Quartic equations at Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuarticEquation.html)

However, it ends there.  The general quintic equation cannot be solved with just basic arithmetic and roots.

[Quintic equations at Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuinticEquation.html)

Comment: this is a special case that is simple though

Comment: Indeed.  I just meant that if the general case is known then this special case must be too.  At higher degrees, the distinction is more interesting since some special cases might have solutions even though the general case does not.

Answer (score -1):

It could be $a = -2, b = 2, x = 1$.